# Multiply two fields in django form and populate third filed with the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I am creating a form in my django app like this:

**views.py**

```
@method_decorator([login_required, client_required], name='dispatch')
class MaterialRequestFormView(CreateView):
    model = MaterialRequest
    template_name = 'packsapp/client/materialRequestForm.html'
    fields = "__all__"

    def form_valid (self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'The material request was created with success!')
        return redirect('client:mat_req_table')
```

**models.py**

```
class MaterialRequest(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='allotment_sales')
    flow = models.ForeignKey(Flow, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='flow')
    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='kit')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_allocated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    quantity_p1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quantity_p2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quantity_p3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quantity_p4 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quantity_p5 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**html**

```
 <h2>Material Request Form</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-12">
            <form method="post" id="MaterialRequestForm" data-kit-url="{% url 'employee:ajax_load_kit' %}"
                  data-product-url="{% url 'employee:ajax_load_product' %}"
                  novalidate>
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="products-table">

    </div>

    <script>

        $("#id_flow").change(function () {
            console.log("function running");
            var url = $("#MaterialRequestForm").attr("data-kit-url");
            var flowId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({

                url: url,
                data: {
                    'flow': flowId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#id_kit").html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

    <script>

        $("#id_kit").change(function () {
            console.log("function running");
            var url = $("#MaterialRequestForm").attr("data-product-url");
            var kitId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({

                url: url,
                data: {
                    'kit': kitId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#products-table").html(data);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

The ajax is to get the table.

Can I change it such that when I enter the quantity it multiply the `std quantity` from table with that value and fill that in respective columns?

Pic for better clarification:

[image]

The table is created by this:

```
<tbody>
    {% for product in products %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.product_name }}</td>
        {% for i in quantities %}
            {% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
                <td id="q1">{{ i }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

To simplify: Multiply `Quantity` with `Std Qty` and fill `Quantity p1`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to perform this on the client side before data submission. This, as you might suspect, is best done with `javascript`. Since you're already using `jquery`, I'd suggest looking into the `change` handler: https://api.jquery.com/change/

You'd listen for changes on the elements with the `raw data` then compute the new values and fill in the ones that are dynamic. The documentation above has a few examples.

So how would you find out the elements' ids? Use the developer web tools in your browser (normally, `right click > inspect element` will do the trick). Typically, this don't change as long as you don't change the field names but they are also over-writable if you'd like. Just create an actual form (or modelform).

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through easily using jquery.
Give id to the fields in forms.py,

For eg, #std be the id for std & #quantity for quantity field.

```
 $('#quantity').change(function(){
     std = $('#std').val();
     quantity = $('#quantity').val();
     x = parseInt(std) * parseInt(quantity);
     // Now assign x to your respective field 
 });
```

So dynamically value will be changed and you can then simply save it using django form or whatsoever.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `$('#quantity').change(function()` and `$('#quantity').val();`.. same keyword at both places ?

Comment: Just an example to explain the logic, you can create a const for capturing the id then continue the same logic